# Trying to update documents with aggregation

Tags: mongodb

I am having trouble updating documents with aggregation. I have written out this command but am not getting any output and nothing is showing up when I view the documents.

```
db.customers.aggregate([{$match : {state : "PA"}}, {$addFields : {"pastPurchase" : {$switch : {branches: [{case : {_id : 1}, then : ["chair", "desk"]}, {case : {_id : 4}, then: ["chair", "tablet", "usb"]}}}}, {$out : "customers"}])
```

Here is an example of one document:

```
{"id": "1", “name” : “Bill”, "productId": "1", "customerId": "1", "amount": 20.00, “state”: “PA”}
```